# Maple and Java (documentation, plotting in Java on Canvas etc)?

Tags: java, canvas, plot, maple

I am researching the relationship between Java and Maple and their uses.

I have been browsing for information for some time and these are the results:
 1. Maple is written in Java
 2. Maple can call Java user written methods 
 3. Java can use Maple methods

Now I have some questions. Firstly can someone recommend me some documentation/tutorial about Java/Maple relationship/possibilities. I have found some but they are not as extensive as I would like them to be.

How can I plot on a Canvas in Java? I have managed to use Maple libraries in Java code. When engine.evaluate("foo") is called I get the result (of foo) in console. This is a problem with plotting as it is plotted in console.

In addition can someone please tell me if any (or all) of the statements above are false.

Comment: Maple's math engine is written in C.  There are academic papers from the mid-80s covering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maple kernel (computational engine) is written in C, and the Maple Standard GUI is written in Java. The kernel and Std GUI run as separate processes, communicate with each over sockets, and mostly exchange representations of Maple's data structures (DAGs) in the same "dotm" (.m) format that is used to store expressions in its .mla library archive.

The kernel can do an [external-call](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=external_calling) to run user-defined Java code. And the [Java OpenMaple API](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/API) provides mechanisms to run Maple code in the kernel.

But AFAIK there is no mechanism by which the Std GUI alone can do either of those things. No way to force the Java GUI to utilize some method (for something). OpenMaple talks to the kernel, not the Java GUI.

You could use OpenMaple to get the kernel to turn Maple language code into a Maple structure DAG which represents a Maple PLOT. But there's no function in the Java GUI for plotting it to *any* canvas, that which is available to OpenMaple, AFAIK.

If I properly understand the goals behind your 3 points, then I suspect that all are wrong in the ways that matter.

Comment: Thank you, this answer made me rethink my views on the subject.